# Facebook authentication without redirect

Tags: facebook, node.js

I use nodejs, but i can't use a redirect callback (long story! :D) because i don't have access to server reference.
You can image that a user create his application and set a config file with appID, appSecret and userID.
How can this user (user is the owner of application) set the permissions to his application? (without redirect!)
If this user uses only the application token, he can't post a message in his wall...

Or does it make sense to create another server on another port? I don't know.

Comment: Automatically redirecting to the Auth dialog is bad practice anyway – so why don’t you just use a simple _link_ to call it …?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) use the JavaScript SDK for login, no redirection needed:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/getting-started-web/

See "FB.login" with the scope parameter for additional permissions.

Comment: I use nodejs, i'm in server-side but i don't have the possibility to use redirect. Umh...it's difficult to explain.
Can you give me more suggestions? Or How can I create the User Token?

Comment: take a look at the links, it´s all explained very well in the facebooki docs. forget about the server, it does not matter if you are using nodejs or php or whatever. just use the javascript sdk, it is only client side.